# C# の Digit separator / 桁区切り文字を含む文字列を実行時に数値に変換するには？

Tags: c#

C# を含む最近の言語処理系では、数値定数に桁区切り文字を入れることができて、長めの数値の視認性を高めることができます。

**例:**

```
pi = 3.1415_9265;
```

これと同様の文字列を実行時に数値に変換するメソッドなどは用意されているのでしょうか？
簡単に `int.parse( "123_456" );` とやってみましたが、実行時エラーになってしまいました。

```
System.FormatException
  Message=Input string was not in a correct format.
```

それとも、自分で '_' / アンダースコアを取り除かなければいけない？

Comment: 一応、`NumberGroupSeparator` と `NumberStyles` を指定すれば可能です。https://dotnetfiddle.net/4atl09 ただ、`NumberGroupSeparator` は整数部分のみしか処理してくれません(`3.1415_9265` は変換されずエラーになります)。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「自分で '_' / アンダースコアを取り除かなければいけない」です。

.NETラインタイムとしては、`_` が何を意味する記号なのか把握できません。同様にアルファベットが含まれた時、それが16進表記なのかゴミなのかも自動的に解釈することは不可能です。開発者が明示的に指定する必要があります。
どのようなバリエーションがあり得るのか、 [`NumberStyles` 列挙型](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0) で指定することになりますが、ここに用意されていない指定はできないということになります。

---

> とすると、言語処理系内の表記と、実行時の記法が異なる。ということですね。

はい、異なります。例えばソースコードにおいて小数点は必ず `.` ですが、実行時は地域に応じて、 `.` だったり `,` だったり動的に変化します。
`"123,456"`とあった場合に、ソースコードにおいてはコンパイル環境でコードの意味が変わるのは困るため一意に定まるようになっていますが、実行時においては地域に応じた解釈がされるべき、一意に定まるべきではない、という相反する要求があります。そのため、両者は全く別の機能であると理解してください。

Comment: とすると、言語処理系内の表記と、実行時の記法が異なる。ということですね。

ご指摘の通り、.NET は古いバージョンを含めた複数の言語処理系を処理しなければいけないので、最新の記法をサポートすることはできないですね。その観点は忘れていました。
ざっと見た限りでは、オプションで管理できそうもないので、手作業で処理します。

Comment: 厳密には「言語処理系内の表記と、実行時の記法が異なる。」のではなくて、「数値定数」に記述可能なフォーマットと、「文字列から数値に変換する関数/メソッド」の文字列に記述可能なフォーマットが異なる、ということでしょう。`int.parse( "123_456" );`の`"123_456"`は数値定数ではなくて文字列定数ですね。コンパイラ系の言語はそういう差があるのが多そうで、インタプリタ/スクリプト系の言語では両方サポートしているのが多そうです。

Comment: @Kawasaki 回答に加筆しましたので確認をお願いします。